# Recent (one year) change in the handout mode of Beamer?

Tags: beamer

Help requested for the handout mode of the beamer class.

I have been using it fairly minimally for a few years. About a year ago the handout mode stopped producing all the pages.  The presentation mode works fine.

This is my preamble for the handout:

```
 \documentclass[xcolor=pst,dvips,11pt,handout]{beamer}
 %
 \usepackage{pgfpages}
 \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letterpaper, border shrink=4mm,landscape]
 \mode<handout>{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black!5}}
```

Used to work fine, now does not.  Any clue would be appreciated.

Running latest TexLive version on linux, Mint 17.

Comment: Is "stopped producing all the pages" = "produces 0 pages as output"? Is "latest TeX Live" = "TeX Live 2014"?

Comment: Only three pages out of 10 are produced, oddly positioned. Yes, TeXLive 2014.  The puzzle is about the change, which appeared before the most recent update.  Also is not related to the Mint distribution, since I saw it on Ubuntu 12.04 as well.

Comment: It's just difficult to address this question, since it's very broad - it's anybody's guess. You need to focus the problem before it can be addressed properly.

Comment: Thank you @Werner.   I suppose my expectation was to hear that yes, some basic functionality changed, since the files I use I have been using now for four years, tweaking them every time I teach the course, but the beamer machinery was not touched.  And then --- I do not get the handouts.  I removed __all__ preamble lines except the four above, and the issue persists.  The rest of the MWE consisted of twelve repeats of  \begin{frame}...minimal text...end{frame}, bracketed by \open and \close document.  The above preamble shows frames one, five and nine, w/o the rest...

Comment: So you updated your distribution for the first time in four years? Your use of `4 on 1` seems to be related to the fact that only "pages" 1, 5 and 9 are shown.

Comment: Since I use linux distributions, I update whenever the relevant update/upgrade recommends, except that I keep to the long-term versions.  I realize the numbers I mentioned are all 1 modulo 4, but I have seen no mention or reference how to get all of them in the handout mode.  I get the same result from several linux systems I have access to, and am going for more...

Comment: See [this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17372888#17372888). Joseph - the current maintainer - mentions that some solution would require package version numbers in order to see whether some change may have caused the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: We need to know `beamer` versions here: what does `\listfiles` show in the log? I'm suspicious this might be a `pgf` issue, perhaps just in `dvips` mode, as I use a very similar set up and don't see the problem, but use direct PDF output. Also, we'll really need some minimal example (with filler text) to try to help.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, @Werner, JosephWright (I may only notify one): teaching pressure kept me away. I created a mwe, ran it with \listfiles. Since I do not know what is material, my preference was to keep it all. It is a single file which I did not want to pile here --- so it is in my personal website, at [http://www.cs.wpi.edu/~hofri/mwe.listfiles ]  The fault is related to pgf; if I %out the \pgfpagesuselayout.... statement the entire content is correctly in the output file, but clearly one page at a time. Much obliged!